# How to get the price and the id from request.POST.getlist()?

Tags: django

i tried to get two value from request.POST.getlist() what i am doing is :

```
for price in request.POST.getlist('price')
   print(price)
```

what if I want to get two values with two keys i mean i want the price and the id ??

```
for price, id in request.POST.getlist('price','id') /something like that ???
```

i trying to submit the data to a form :

```
 for prix in request.POST.getlist('prix'):

  na = AssociationForm({'Prix_Unitaire':str(round(float(request.POST['prix']),2)),'Quantite':request.POST['quantite']},instance=Association())
             na.save()
```

Comment: what do your post data look like?

Comment: i added some info

Comment: every row containe the price and the quantity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your post data look like as below:
{"price":[2,3,4], "id":[1,2,3]}

```
for price, id in zip(request.POST.getlist('price'), reqest.POST.getlist('id')):
    # do your business here
```